What is the importance of voting in the National Assembly building and not elsewhere?
With regard to the martial law declaration in South Korea yesterday: how important is it to convene in the National Assembly building? If the South Korean MPs had convened elsewhere because they were blocked from entering the building, would the vote result be valid?
Edit: I am more interested in the procedure and legality, but also appreciate comments on the cultural/symbolic aspect.

Title and body ask slightly different questions. Are you more interested in the symbolism/importance or in the legality? The second would be like: "It's a beautiful Summer day, so Parliament decides to move to a park and vote there, would it be legal?" and would be more for law.stackexchange.

It might help if you explain what specific vote you were interested in, as rules may differ e.g. between procedural/administrative and legislative votes, and votes of the full assembly vs committees etc.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on law.stackexchange.com

@JBentley I don't think this is a good fit for law SE either.

@JoeW I think it's fine there. The question boils down to the last sentence of the first paragraph ("... would the vote result be valid?") which is a purely legal question.

(Note:  the parliamentary vote was to repeal the martial declared only hours before by the president)
Don't know about the legal aspects, but psychological aspects count for a lot in these things.  Typically, during a coup, control of official buildings matters and both sides expend a great deal of energy trying to control them.
This type of affair often gets decided on bluffing, appearance and elan, esp. against a President nominally in charge of the armed forces.  Above all you want to project legitimacy and a fait-accompli. Main reason is that, at the beginning, the people doing the coup are a minority and the people actively countering it are also a minority.  They both vie to influence the greater masses of citizens and military and police.
Much better to have the MPs publicly be seen to hold out, and vote (and possibly get tear-gassed, arrested or shot at), in the official legislative building, where they belong, openly. Rather than skulking off elsewhere and doing the exact same thing.
Plus, other locations would have been hard to arrange and keep secret on the fly, so it would have complicated things and not made it much safer for the MPs.
Last, in practice, the legality of the location, had the vote taken place elsewhere, would have most likely have been secondary.  Provided the vote annulling martial law had been made sufficiently public, people would have a) ignored it to side with the president or b) sided with Parliament.  By the time it got to a court to decide, the coup would have been over, one way or the other.

For a historical counter-example, see the Serment du Jeu de Paume (which wasn't exactly a coup situation)
